# ViewState value doesn't get extracted from Request

Tags: regex, xpath, jmeter, viewstate

i need to login to a jsf page. But when i try to extract the ViewState value it doesn't work.

The ViewState input field looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="-2660902297226015539:-7257444434252784696" autocomplete="off" />
```

I use the XPath Extractor with the following query:

```
//input[@id='javax.faces.ViewState']/@value
```

The ViewState parameter in the Login request looks like this:
[image: ViewState paramater]

The test plan looks like this:

[image]

But when i send the POST Data looks like this:

```
POST data:
j_idt52=j_idt52&j_idt52%3Aj_idt53%3Aj_idt78%3AloginUsername%3AinputField=XXXXX&
j_idt52%3Aj_idt53%3Aj_idt78%3AloginPassword%3AinputSecretField=XXXXXX&
j_idt52%3Aj_idt53%3Aj_idt78%3AloginSend=Login&j_idt52%3Aj_idt53%
3Aj_idt78_active=0&javax.faces.ViewState=
```

**It doesn't insert the ViewState.**

I also tried to use the Regular Expressions Exctrator with the following expression:

```
<input type="hidden" name="javax\.faces\.ViewState" id="javax\.faces\.ViewState" value="(\w+?)"
```

Then the POST data looks like this:

```
 POST data:
 j_idt52=j_idt52&j_idt52%3Aj_idt53%3Aj_idt78%3AloginUsername%3AinputField=XXXXXX
 &j_idt52%3Aj_idt53%3Aj_idt78%3AloginPassword%3AinputSecretField=XXXXXX&
 j_idt52%3Aj_idt53%3Aj_idt78%3AloginSend=Login&j_idt52%3Aj_idt53%
 3Aj_idt78_active=0
 &javax.faces.ViewState=%24%7BViewState%7D
```

Encoded the parameter is:

```
javax.faces.ViewState=${ViewState}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: When I add default values for both post processors it says that the ViewState value was not fround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to add the XPath Extractor to the HTTP Request, not like seen in the test plan screenshot.